# Where does useTranslate pull the translations from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to learn react with NextJS and bought [this template.](https://pickbazar-react-doc.vercel.app/how-it-works#shop-rest) Under src/pages/terms.tsx I find the following code that is super complicated.

What does the ? in content?.map do?

How is passing `{t(title)}` translated into "Purpose" when `t(title)` from terms yields back the string `'terms-one-title'`. Is there somewhere useTranslation is pulling the translations from? I can't find it.

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

export default function TermsPage() {
  const { t } = useTranslation('terms');
  const { title, date, content } = termsAndServices;

  return (
    <>
      <section className="mx-auto w-full max-w-1920 bg-light py-8 px-4 lg:py-10 lg:px-8 xl:py-14 xl:px-16 2xl:px-20">
          <div className="md:w-9/12 md:pb-10 ltr:md:pl-8 rtl:md:pr-8">
            {content?.map((item) => (
              <Element
                key={item.title}
                name={makeTitleToDOMId(item.title)}
                className="mb-10"
              >
                <h2 className="mb-4 text-lg font-bold text-heading md:text-xl lg:text-2xl">
                  {t(item.title)}
                </h2>
                <div
                  className="leading-loose text-body-dark"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t(item.description) }}
                />
              </Element>
            ))}
          </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

terms.ts

```
export const termsAndServices = {
  title: 'terms-main-title',
  date: '01/01/2020',
  content: [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'terms-one-title',
      description: 'terms-one-description',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'terms-two-title',
      description: 'terms-two-description',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: 'terms-three-title',
      description: 'terms-three-description',
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      title: 'terms-four-title',
      description: 'terms-four-description',
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      title: 'terms-five-title',
      description: 'terms-five-description',
    },
    {
      id: '6',
      title: 'terms-six-title',
      description: 'terms-six-description',
    },
  ],
};
```

Element.d.ts

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface ElementProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {
    name: string;
    id?: string | undefined;
}

export default class Element extends React.Component<ElementProps> {}
```

Comment: Does the template use something other than the default translation config, e.g., where the translations are? https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#2-translation-content

Comment: That's it! It's not in /src but instead /public/locales/en/terms.json is this a standard way to do this? It seems very complicated.

Comment: It’s not source code, it’s data (ultimately). Translations are very often separate files, and they have to go *somewhere* :)

Comment: Makes sense. I started reading the translation docs and it makes much more sense. Thanks to everyone for the help. It really was the direction I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. content? - if the content exists. Since you are taking an array from a file, you can probably remove the '?'
2. You can check where your translations are in a file named i18n.ts (or something like that) at the root of your project. Casual in the public/locales folder

Comment: Thanks for answering both questions! I've been messing around with the content? in console.log and you are right it doesn't matter so long as that piece is defined. Who ever wrote this code was much better than me so it's a good piece for me to learn from.